# Как на чистом Си можно завершить обработку потока stdin после нажатия клавиши Enter?

Tags: c, циклы

Как можно завершить цикл после нажатия клавиши "Enter" на ванильном C?

```
while(scanf("%d", var)!=EOF) 
    printf("%d + %d = %d", var, var, 2*var)
```

На крайний случай можно использовать posix-функции.

Comment: А что возвращает `scanf` если просто нажать Enter? Наверное, 0?

Comment: Ничего, в том то и проблема.

Comment: ээээ... он не может возвращать «ничего», у него [тип возвращаемого значения](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) — `int`.

Comment: @VladD `scanf` будет ждать до тех пор, пока пользователь не введет хотя бы один не-whitespace символ.

Comment: @VisioN: жаль :-(

Comment: @VladD Да не, наоборот, удобно. Особенно, когда нужно распарсить файл игнорируя возможные пробелы и табы.

Comment: @VisioN: Жалко, что нет метода управлять этим.

Comment: @StackOverflowRu А вам обязательно тут использовать `scanf`? Как насчет банальный `gets` + `atoi`?

Comment: Может можно через posix-api хоть как-нибудь это сделать, без использования сторонних библиотек?

Comment: Нет, scanf не обязательно. Про 'atoi' не додумался, сейчас опробую.

Comment: Ладно, спасибо, в итоге сделал через gets. Правда код чутка громоздким получается, ну да ладно.

Comment: @StackOverflowRu Я привел пример кода в ответе. Данный вариант должен работать как требуется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле особенность `scanf` не позволит вам вводить числа вплоть до пустой строки, поскольку `scanf` будет всегда ждать вводимого числа, игнорируя все пустые символы (пробелы, табуляцию и новые строки).

Поэтому проще будет все реализовать через `gets` (или не deprecated `fgets`):

```
int main()
{
    char s[32];
    int n;

    while (fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin) != 0 && *s != '\n') {
        n = atoi(s);  // конвертация строки в число
        printf("%d + %d = %d\n", n, n, n * 2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: scanf будет делать то, что его попросят. В том числе, можно заставить его проверять пробельные символы.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
  {
  int x;

  for (char *format="%d"; scanf(format, &x) == 1; format="%*[ ]%d")
    printf("%d + %d = %d\n", x, x, x+x);

  return 0;
  }
```

Предполагается, что требуется ввести хотя бы одно значение.