# Прервать считывание чисел

Tags: c++, vector

Нужно считать последовательность целых чисел и поместить их в вектор. Как сделать так, чтобы числа считывались именно до первого нажатия **Enter**?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<int> vec;
    int a;
    int sum = 0;
    while(cin >> a){
        vec.push_back(a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Такой вариант](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416088/178988) годится, или надо именно через `cin`?

```
for (char *format="%d"; scanf(format, &x) == 1; format="%*[ ]%d")
  v.push_back(x);
```

Нужно хотя бы одно число.

Comment: Я бы добавил после `for (...) ...` проверку (`int c = getchar(); if (c != '\n') ...`), что выход произошел именно по `\n` (и заодно сразу же убрал его из потока).

Answer (score 2):

Проще всего, вероятно, сначала считать строку при помощи `getline`:

```
string s;
getline(cin, s);
```

а затем разбить её на числа, используя `istringstream`:

```
istringstream iss(s);
int n;
vector<int> v;
while (iss >> n)
    v.push_back(n);
```

(стандартное [решение через `istream_iterator` и `back_inserter`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16727125/276994) кажется мне совершенно нечитаемым).

Полный пример (http://ideone.com/Kx7E2V):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    getline(cin, s);
    istringstream iss(s);
    int n;
    vector<int> v;
    while (iss >> n)
        v.push_back(n);
    for (auto m : v)
        cout << m << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

Ввод:

> 1 2 3
>   4 5 6

Вывод:

> 1 2 3

Answer (score 0):

если я правильно понял, что нужно получить числа идущие подряд в строке ввода и подтверждением конца ввода используется клавиша ввода. то можно применить такой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<int> v;
    string s, buf;

    getline(cin, s); // считали все в строку

    s.push_back(' '); // заэкранировали конец строки для получения последнего числа

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){ // цикл в котором сканируются все числа из строки
        if (s[i] != ' '){ // если не пробел
            buf += s[i]; // ложить очередной символ в буфер
        } else {
            if (buf.length() != 0) // если строка не пустая
                v.push_back(atoi(buf.c_str())); // преоброзовать в число и положить в вектор

            buf.clear(); // очищаем буфер под следующие символы
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) // проверка
        cout << v[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```