# C++. Программа пропускает строчку кода(считывание переменной)

Tags: c++, потоки-данных, вектор

Доброго времени суток.
Возникла проблема с С++. Если кратко - в одной строчке не происходит считывание с помощью потока ввода cin.
Код ниже. Место где происходит ошибка - обозначено комментарием. Пробовал очищать поток перед считыванием *user_num_to_sum* с помощью *cin.clear()* - don't help.

```
#include <iostream> //cin, cout
#include <conio.h> //_getch()
#include <vector> //vector

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::vector;


int main () {
    vector<int> numbers; // вектор из целых чисел
    int num = 0; // число которое заносим в конец вектора
    int user_num_to_sum = 0; // число элементов вектора для суммирования(пример: если число 3, то суммируем первые 3 элемента)

    cout << "Write a few numbers: \n";
    while(cin >> num) {
        numbers.push_back(num);// заносим числа в вектор
        }
    cout << "How much elements of vector do you want to sum?\n";
    cin >> user_num_to_sum; // ERROR: программа пропускает данную строчку и выполняет следующую подставляя в user_num_to_sum значение 0, которое было задано при инициализации.
    cout << "The sum of first " << user_num_to_sum << " numbers -> ";

//код еще не готов полностью, программа смысла не имеет

    _getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Я и останавливаю цикл while(cin >> num) вводом ошибочного символа '|'. Данный приём использует в своей книге Страуструп. Вот только потом почему-то после остановки цикла не срабатывает считывание целого числа user_num_to_sum.

P.S. Сработал вариант с использованием *cin.clear()*, но только в случае завершения ввода данных в вектор путём нажатия Ctrl+Z. 
Если же завершить его путём ввода неверных данных(к примеру '|' при считывании данных типа int), то *cin.clear()* не срабатывает. Вопрос: почему?

Comment: А как Вы прекращаете заполнение вектора?

Comment: PS Мне `cin.clear()` помог.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while(cin >> num) { // Пока мы можем прочитать int, читаем его
  ... // и что-то делаем
}

// Вышли из цикла, т. к. int прочитать нельзя
... // Тут мы ничего не читали
cin >> user_num_to_sum; // Опа! Чиатем ещё int
```

Но ведь состояние потока не изменилось - int как нельзя было прочитать, так и сейчас нельзя.

Если ввод последовательности чисел заканчивается неким нечисловым вводом, следует прочитать это нечто как строку и только потом считывать следующее число. Если же ввод завершался нажатием ctrl+z, то там вроде вообще eof выставляется.

Также для сброса маркера ошибки надо перед чтением вызвать `cin.clear()`.

Comment: Кстати, если ввод завершается нажатием ctrl+Z, то cin.clear() замечательно решает проблему (как я и делал) и последнее (после цикла) число замечательно читается.

Comment: Да, действительно работает.
Не сочтите за глупость, я только учусь, но почему _cin.clear()_ не очищает последний ошибочный ввод к примеру символа '|'?

Comment: @andy.37, спасибо, буду знать. Вообще, я как-то `scanf` предпочитаю - у него куча фокусов с форматом есть. Например, такое: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/439205/178988

Comment: @ТарасСус, добавьте, пожалуйста Ваш последний комментарий в сам вопрос, или задайте новый, я бы и сам с удовольствием узнал бы на него ответ)

Answer (score 4):

```
while(cin >> num) {
    numbers.push_back(num);// заносим числа в вектор
    }
std::string s;
cin.clear(); // сбрасываем ошибку в cin
cin >> s; // убираем из cin нечисловые символы
cout << "How much elements of vector do you want to sum?\n";
cin >> user_num_to_sum; // ERROR: программа пропускает данную строчку и выполняет следующую подставляя в user_num_to_sum значение 0, которое было задано при инициализации.
```

Вот так Ваш код будет работать корректно при завершении заполнения вектора любым нечисловым символом.

Собственно, ответ на последний вопрос: cin.clear() сбрасывает флаги (состояние) ошибки в потоке, но последний введенный символ (группа символов) в нем остается, поэтому их нужно оттуда убрать, например в какую-то ненужную строку.

П.С. Вопрос получился неожиданно интересным и заслуживает поощрения в виде плюса.

П.П.С. Нашелся вариант без лишней переменной (проверил, нужно `#include <limits>`)

```
cout << "Write a few numbers (end with any non-number input): \n";
while(cin >> num) {
    numbers.push_back(num);// заносим числа в вектор
    }
cin.clear(); // сбрасываем флаг ошибки
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // пропускаем все до символа новой строки
cout << "How much elements of vector do you want to sum?\n";
cin >> user_num_to_sum;
```

Comment: http://ideone.com/7WnmmU

Comment: http://ideone.com/UhPFH7 - а так с перенаправлением ввода не работает. Но по идее же должно, при реальной консоли?

Comment: @Qwertiy нашел еще вот что, там пример, практически как у ТС: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore

Comment: Не зря я scanf люблю :)