# Подскажите, как прервать ввод, если пользователь захочет ввести не 10 элементов, а 3 элемента (не используя динамический массив)

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    setlocale(0,"");
    int n;
    double xsum=0, ysum=0,x[100],xs=0,ys=0;
    for (int i=1;i<=10;i++){
        do { 
        cout << "Введите элементы массива чисел ["<<i<<"]: ";
        if ((cin >> x[i])){ 
            n++; 
            break; 
        }
        cout << "Ошибка, повторите ввод!" <<endl; 
        cin.clear(); 
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // устанавливает максимальное количество символов для игнорирования
    }while (true);
    }
    for (int i=1; i<=n-1; i++) { 
        if(i % 2 == 0) {                      // проверка на четность
            xsum+=x[i];                         // сумма четных   
            xs++;                               // количество четных
        }
        else {
            ysum+=x[i];                         // сумма нечетных
            ys++;                               // кол-во нечетных  
        }
    }
    cout<<"Результат = "<<(ysum/ys)/(xsum/xs)<<endl;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Производите считывание посимвольно пока не будет введено 10 символов или не будет конца строки.

```
do {
    c = getchar();
    i++;
    //далее помещаете с в массив по индексу i
} while(c != '\n' && i < 10);
```

Как-то так. Основная мысль тут, далее додумайте...

Answer (score 0):

На основе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/439205/178988

```
const char *format="%d";
for (int i = 1; scanf(format, x+i) == 1; ++i, format="%*[ ]%d");
```