# Попадаю в вечный цикл

Tags: c++, while

Решаю задачку где часть задания - считать числа введенные через пробел. Вроде и нашел подходящий код, ибо мой не работал. Но незадача, попадаю в вечный цикл, ибо дальше цикла вообще ничего не происходит и программа стоит на месте.

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> numbers;
    int n;
    while (cin >> n) {
        numbers.push_back(n);        
    }
    int a = numbers.size();
    for (int b = 0; b < a; b++) { // ЭТО ПРОВЕРКА МАССИВА, СЮДА ПРОГРАММА НЕ ДОХОДИТ, ПРОСТО НИЧЕГО НЕ ПРОИСХОДИТ
        cout << numbers[b];
    }

    if (numbers[0] >= 1 && numbers[1] >= 1 && numbers[2] <= pow(10, 18)) {
        int c = (int)pow(numbers[0], numbers[1]);
        int c2 = (int)c;
        int d = c % numbers[2];
        if (d > 0) {
            cout << "\n" << d;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Сколько чисел — известно? Или до первого не числа?

Comment: 3 числа нужно ввести. Но в перспективе хочу понять как ввести сколько угодно таких чисел

Comment: Вы для начала побольше печати по ходу исполнения программы вставьте, станет ясно что и где идет не так

Comment: Проблема уже исправлена.

Answer (score 1):

Вот, например, пока целые числа успешно читаюся — примерно так:

```
vector<int> numbers;
int n;
while(cin >> n) numbers.push_back(n);
```

Если дадите **точно сформулированное** задание, можно будет делать под него. Пока что вы задание изложили крайне расплывчато.

Comment: Пока что задание - как раз ввести эти числа. Использовал ваш код - по прежнему ничего, ввожу числа в консоль, а результата ноль, программа ничего не делает и не завершается.

Comment: Введите НЕ число, или нажмите Ctrl-Z (в Windows, в Linux Ctrl-D). Например: https://ideone.com/etdwWI

Answer (score 1):

После ввода чисел нажми <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

Comment: ага, работает нужно было просто неправильный символ ввести. А более "элегантное" решение можно найти?

Comment: @MyLittleMasya, это нормальный, если планируется ввод из файла. Ещё можно запрашивать сначала количество чисел или вводить до перевода строки: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/439202/178988 & https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/415920/178988.

Comment: ну я имею ввиду, чтобы ввод сам заканчивался при нажатии enter

Comment: @MyLittleMasya, я же 2 ссылки дал.